# Can patches on different files be a part of a single patch series?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, patch

Do patches on different files qualify as a patch series?

I made 5 patches in total, 3 of which are changes to 3 different files, and 2 of which are changes to another single file. I assume that the 2 patches on the single file qualify as a series of patches, but my question is do all 5 patches qualify as a series of patches? Keep in mind that 2 of the patches make changes to a single file and the other 3 patches make changes to 3 different files.

Thank you for reading this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, patches to different files can qualify as a patch series. Loosely defined, a patch series is a series of patches which should be applied one after the other; more precise definitions depend on the target project’s practices.

One common pattern for patch series is to add a new feature, possibly as several patches, then use it; the “define” versus “use” parts will often touch different files.

In most cases, I would use a patch *series* to submit multiple patches which don’t make sense without each other. If individual patches are useful on their own, I would submit them individually. The general use for a patch series is to split up a complex change into multiple steps, in order to simplify review (whether the initial review, or “review“ when people look at the history).

Comment: But what if it doesn't really matter what order they're applied in? Do I get to number them in a random order? These patches do not depend on each other, they're on completely different files except for 2 which have already been sent as 1/2 and 2/2

Comment: Are the patches related? What project is this on?

Comment: These patches are on the Linux kernel (drivers/staging).

Comment: Are the patches related?

Comment: Well they're on different files for the same driver. Does that count as related? If what you mean by related is does it matter which order they're applied in, no. Except for the 2 patches on the same file that have already been put in a series as 1/2 and 2/2.

Comment: See my update. If the patches are useful individually, submit them individually. Otherwise, submit them as a series, using the git history to control the patch numbering (`git format-patch`).

Comment: Thank you for answering the question :)